# Why $\phi \lor \neg \phi $ is not allowed in intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

Why is $\phi \lor \neg\phi$ not allowed in intuitionistic logic?
My professor said this was because intuitionistic logic must have concrete construction.

Further, why is it not possible to write a truth table in intuitionistic logic?

Comment: What is *intruvistic*?

Comment: I think the term you're after is "intuitionistic".

Comment: $\phi\land\neg\phi$ is a contradiction in _any_ kind of logic I know.

Comment: Truth tables don't form a complete semantics for intuitionistic propositional logic. You can write a truth table; it just won't tell you if the relevant formula is valid (though it can tell you that it is invalid).

Comment: I'm guessing that when you write $\phi \land \neg \phi$ (phi and not phi), you meant to write $\phi \lor \neg \phi$ (phi or not phi)? Is that right?

Comment: The thing your professor was probably referring to was the *dis*junction $\varphi\vee\neg\varphi$; this is the one that is usually connected to whether or not you can form an explicit construction.

Comment: Also, are you asking "*how can we show* that this is not admissible in intuitionistic logic", or are you asking "*what is the motivation* behind making this inadmissible in intuitionistic logic"? Or something else?

Comment: I replaced $\land$ with $\lor$ in the question because the question is clearly about the law of excluded middle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intuitionistic logic does not consider $\phi\lor\neg\phi$ to be universally valid **because that's the way "intuitionistic logic" is defined**.

The word "intuitionistic" refers to the *intuitionists*, a grouping of mathematicians who in the first part of the 1900s made up one side of a Great Controversy about what should be considered a valid proof. Among the arguments they didn't accept were ones of the form

> Either $\phi$ is true or it is not. We don't know which, but in each of those cases $\psi$ must be true, so $\psi$ is definitely true.

What we call "intuitionistic logic" today is, however, not the work of the intuitionists themselves. On the contrary the most prominent intuitionists tended to vehemently deny that the validity of an argument could be reduced to a system of rigid rules -- they appealed instead to the mathematician's *intuition*, hence the name. The system taught in modern textbooks is later workers' attempt to *nevertheless* find a formal definition that would align more-or-less with what the intuitionists were known to consider good proofs.

So arguably "the reason" why intuitionistic logic doesn't allow the law of excluded middle is simply that it is designed to mimic the opinions of Brouwer and his followers, who did not accept arguments of the above form.

From a modern perspective one might say that intuitionistic logic is *by definition* the study of what is still provable if one excludes appeals to the law of excluded middle (or other principles that turn out to be equivalent to it).

Even more, though, intuitionistic logic is well suited for expressing arguments in a style where *proving something exists* also provides an algorithm for constructing it. (The logic is only one part of this program; one also needs to choose one's axioms so they correspond to meaningful "constructive" steps). This is of importance in computer science and allied fields of mathematics, which is a main reason intuitionistic logic is still being studied as more than a technical curiosity.

It so turns out that the resulting notion of provability cannot be described using truth tables in the simple way classical propositional logic can. This is not a design goal, however -- it's just what happens to follow from the set of proof rules we're studying.

Comment: Intuitionistic logic also arises naturally in category theory, as it is very closely related to the notion of a cartesian closed category. For example, Heyting algebras are precisely the lattices which are cartesian closed categories. Toposes are systems of intuitionistic higher order logic (aka intuitionistic set theory).

Comment: +1: nice answer: out of interest, can you name some early intuitionists apart from Brouwer who scorned formalism?

Comment: @RobArthan: No; I am not that familiar with the history. (In fact I cannot name _any_ early intuitionists apart from Brouwer, full stop, except to the extent Kronecker is usually considered a forerunner -- but he was a generation or so earlier).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: interesting! I have a suspicion (completely unsupported by any real historical research on my part) that it was only Brouwer himself amongst the early writers on intuitionism who had an aversion to formalism viewed as the arithmetization of metamathematics and that others such as Heyting and Kolmogorov revelled in it.

Comment: "Even more, though, intuitionistic logic is well suited for expressing arguments in a style where proving something exists also provides an algorithm for constructing it."
For example, the typical interval halving proof of the intermediate-value theorem invokes the so-called lesser limited principle of omniscience (llpo). In the context of the ivt, llpo is how we are able to decide either $f\left(\frac{1}{2}(a+b)\right) \geq c$ or else $f\left(\frac{1}{2}(a+b)\right) \leq c$. However llpo is known to be nonconstructive.
+1 for thorough answer

Comment: What's $\psi$ in the quote?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Something that follows (separately) from each of $\phi$ or $\neg\phi$.